# Writing custom [Authorize] attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, authorize-attribute

I reading [this](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/AuthorizeAttribute.cs) documentation trying to find where should I replace a *connection string* or something related to database management to override in my `CustomAuthorize` attribute to get the following behavior:

```
public override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
{
    //Check if the actual user is in the roles provided
    if(user.HasRole(Roles))
    {
        true;
    }
    else
    {
        false;
    }
}
```

**What I don't know**:

- How the class knows where and which is my `Users` and `Roles` table to work with?

Comment: It doesn't. You need to add that logic yourself.

Comment: Are you using the built in Membership and Role providers?

Comment: No, I'm trying to work with simple user tables for the membership.

Answer (score 0):

First authenticate the user and create an authenticated cookie for their session, something like this:

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, model.Email, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddDays(1), false, model.Email);

string hashedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);

HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, hashedTicket);

HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

Next step, when the application tries to authenticate:

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var authCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];

    if (authCookie != null)
    {
        var authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
        var user = this.UserService.GetUserByEmail(authTicket.Name);

        var identity = new GenericIdentity(authTicket.Name, "Forms");

        // Get the stored user roles
        HttpContext.Current.User = new GenericPrincipal(identity, user.Roles);
    }
}
```

Then you should be able to use:

```
protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
{
    if (httpContext.User.IsInRole("admin"))
    {

    }
}
```